# How to use If statements in a stream?

Tags: java, if-statement, java-8, java-stream

I have to write a method that gets an Integer List and converts it into a String by adding "e" in front a number if it is even or "u" if it is uneven and then seperates them by ",".
Example: Input:List with numbers 1,2,4,3-->Output:"u1,e2,e4,u3".
The Problem is that I have to do it using lambda expressions and streams and I dont know how to differentiate between even and uneven numbers with them.

If I do it like this i can only do it for even or uneven Numbers:

```
public static String getString(List<Integer> list){
    String s = list.stream()
            .map(Object::toString)
            .filter(i->Integer.parseInt(i)%2==0)
            .map(i->"g"+i)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    return s;

}
```

How can i use something like an If statement in a stream to decide whether to put "e" or "u" in front of the number?

Comment: Get rid of your `filter()` call and change the `map()` call as appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put the condition in the `map` operation. The easiest way is using the ternary condition operator.

BTW, there's no reason to convert the `Integer` to a `String` and then parse it again to an `int`.

```
public static String getString(List<Integer> list){
    return list.stream()
               .map(i->i%2==0?"e"+i:"u"+i)
               .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

EDIT: you can also use an `if-else` statement, but that would look less elegant:

```
public static String getString(List<Integer> list){
    return list.stream()
               .map(i -> {
                    if (i%2==0) {
                        return "e"+i;
                    } else {
                        return "u"+i;
                    }
                })
               .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

Comment: I'd explain why the ternary expression is more convenient - i.e. it returns the result

Comment: darn, too late to edit... edit was going to be - because you could use a normal `if` in a block lambda, but it would be much less convenient.

Comment: @brabster that's true

Comment: Even that small code allows to reduce code duplication: `.map(i -> (i%2 == 0? "e": "u") + i)`

Comment: @Holger I think that this is how it used to be initially if I am not mistaken